# Click a specific button and a checkbox using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, phantomjs, web-crawler

I am trying to click the "detail_search_button" and check the "판매중인 차량" checkbox. But the problem is happened when I tried to find the "detail_search_button".

I used "find" function in BeautifulSoup like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

link = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I'
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.get(link)
sleep(.75)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')

# detail search open
detail_search = soup.find('img', alt='상세검색')
print(detail_search)
```

The result is as below:

```
<img alt="상세검색" class="pointer" id="detail_search_btn" src="http://image.bobaedream.co.kr/renew/images/common_re/btn_search01.gif" title="상세검색열기">
<img alt="검색" class="pointer mr" id="search_click" src="http://image.bobaedream.co.kr/renew/images/common_re/btn_search02.gif" title="검색"> <span class="result" style="padding:0 5px 0 0;"><strong>181,959</strong>대</span> </img></img>
```

The result I would like to have is only the first button without the second button, img alt="검색"....

And then, I would like to click the checkbox of "판매중인차량".

Please give me an advice for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
detail_search = soup.find('img', alt='상세검색')
```

to:

```
detail_search = soup.find('img', {'alt':'상세검색'})
```

The signature of find is:

> find(name, attrs, recursive, string, **kwargs)

Where `attrs` is a dictionary, that takes the attribute name as key and the value as value. You can refer the docs here:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find

Comment: Thanks, sisanared. I deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: this yields the same results, `find` returns two `img`. Also the question about the checkbox is not answered

Comment: this answer is clearly wrong. `find` did work for the OP so no need to reformulate the attributes. Also: `find` never finds more than one node.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see two `img` is because one is nested into the other:

```
<img alt="상세검색" class="pointer" id="detail_search_btn" src="http://image.bobaedream.co.kr/renew/images/common_re/btn_search01.gif" title="상세검색열기">
    <img alt="검색" class="pointer mr" id="search_click" src="http://image.bobaedream.co.kr/renew/images/common_re/btn_search02.gif" title="검색">
        <span class="result" style="padding:0 5px 0 0;">    
        <strong>181,966</strong>대</span>
    </img>
</img>
```

In fact, `find` will **never** find more than one node, if you you're searching for many nodes use `find_all`.

To access the attributes of the parent `img` you use the `attrs` property, e.g. like this:

```
img = soup.find('img', alt='상세검색')
src = img.attrs['src']
```

try a `print(img.attrs)` to see which attributes you have.

> And then, I would like to click the checkbox of "판매중인차량".

I couldn't find anything that matches `판매중인차량` in the document so I need to guess: If you want to search all checkboxes by title, use this:

```
soup.find('input', type="checkbox", title="개인")
```